# Touch not working on HTC with bing map

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, touch, bing

We are having an issue with HTC phones and touch on the map control. This works on the Samsung Focus or the LG Optima for example.

On the map we show "territories" by calling:

```
    MapPolygon shape = new MapPolygon();

shape.Locations = lb.Points;
shape.StrokeThickness = 1;
shape.Tag = lb;
shape.Stroke =

new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

shape.Fill = lb.ColorBrush;
shape.Tag = lb;

_touchTerritoryBehavior =

new TouchBehavior(shape);

_touchTerritoryBehavior.Tap +=

new EventHandler(_touchTerritoryBehavior_Tap);
MyLayer.Children.Add(shape);
```

Where the TouchBehaviour is the same as what's inside the WP7 Training Kit The MyLayer is simply a layer in the map xaml

```
<my:Map Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="{Binding CredentialsProvider}" LogoVisibility="Collapsed"
ZoomLevel="{Binding Zoom, Mode=TwoWay}"
Center="{Binding Center, Mode=TwoWay}" AnimationLevel="None" 
Height="680" Width="480" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" ViewChangeEnd="myMap_ViewChangeEnd" Margin="0,55,0,0">

<my:Map.Mode>
 <my:RoadMode />
</my:Map.Mode>
<my:MapLayer Name="PinLayer">
</my:MapLayer>
<my:MapLayer x:Name="MyLayer">
  <my:MapPolygon Locations="20,-20 20,20 -20,20 -20,-20" Opacity="0.7" />
</my:MapLayer>
```

So why would this not work on HTC Phones yet work perfectly on other WP7 phones?

Comment: Try hooking the application to the debug console and see if touch input is generally detected. For example, use Debug.WriteLine to show that a specific gesture was present.

Comment: It is. It's almost as if the touch event gets eaten by a layer or some other control on the HTC Phones but not the debug or non HTC phones.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the brush class's, this may  help me figure this out....you may be pulling the gesture before you add it to the child if that's the case it wouldn't be there. But for me to know for sure i would need more info on what your doing with that section of code.

Comment: I really doubt it's a problem with the HTC devices. The Windows Phone 7 OS is what handles the events not the brand name of the phone. But with the information you presented, all one can say is "wow, this is weird." debug. good luck.